# How do I flush a tcp socket in Go?

Tags: go, tcp, flush

How do I flush a tcp socket in Go?

I'm sending messages one at a time down a socket, indicating progress to a client, but the messages get bunched up and all sent at the same time. I can't see a flush function anywhere.

The messages are sent a couple of seconds apart, they're <100bytes each, and I'm sending them to localhost. By flushing, I mean I want to clear any buffers stopping them from getting out on the wire; they're clearly being buffered somewhere in this case.

If Go doesn't expose this, can I reach down into the depths of hell to flush the underlying buffer/socket myself?

Comment: There is no `Flush` method, because you can’t flush a TCP socket. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: TCP does the 'bunching' aka segment coalescing. It is normal and desirable. It's a byte-stream protocol, not a messaging protocol. You have to code your receiving application accordingly.

Comment: TCP in Go is unbuffered (no Nagle's) by default. See https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.SetNoDelay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JimB mentioned you can't `Flush()` a `net.Conn`, so if your data-flow is stuttering, it is being buffered elsewhere.

If you - or an intermediate package in your data-flow - is using for example `bufio`:

```
w := bufio.NewWriter(conn)

if _, err := w.WriteString(msg); err != nil {
   return err
}

w.Flush()
```

while the `conn` cannot be flushed, the `bufio.Writer` can.

If, however, your connection is given to you as a pure `io.Writer` type (i.e. `Write()` method only - no `Flush()`) you may try a runtime conversion/check to see if it is "flushable":

```
// var connWriter io.Writer

type Flusher interface {
    // Flush sends any buffered data to the client.
    Flush() error
}

flushable, ok := connWriter.(Flusher) // runtime interface/type check

if !ok {
    log.Println("flushing not supported")
    return
}

flushable.Flush()
```

Comment: However this won't help. The Nagle algorithm and the normal operation of TCP will still cause segment coalescing. The receiver needs to not assume it's a messaging protocol. It isn't.

Comment: @user207421 I thought the Nagle algo. was concerned with efficiency? If one does not care that extra bits/bytes are sent on the wire - and all you really want is real-time delivery - then surely this possible. 1-byte keystrokes are sent in real-time via telnet (and yes costing many bytes extra in both directions).

Comment: @colminator: nagle's algorithm is only one of many tests the TCP stack checks before sending a segment. Disabling it reduces latency, but still does not guarantee every write is sent as a separate packet.

Comment: @colminator 'Surely this is possible' meaning what? There is no guaranteed 1::1 association between sends and receives in TCP. In your Telnet example, keystrokes may indeed be sent one at a time, but there is no guarantee the server will receive them that way, and it is not the purpose of the Nagle algorithm to ensure non-coalesced receives.

Answer (score 1):

Argh! It was being buffered client-side in a bash pipe. Removed the `| ts -s '%.T'` which I had to try to measure the time elapsed between responses, and now it works.

`brew install expect` and `unbuffer my-command -a -b --foo | ts -s '%.T'` to work around this on mac, linux suggestions here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Leaving the question open since I got a good answer on the question I posed, which might help others.